# Why won't it work this way to display what the user has clicked to appear in the modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

I want whatever the user clicks to appear in the modal.  In this case, I want `a random name` to appear in the modal via `displayPerson()` fat arrow function upon the user clicking `<Button/>`.

In between `<Modal/>`, I'm trying to display it, but it's not working.  It's just a blank screen.

The modal has no issues in terms of it being toggled and/or closing with the use of redux.  The only issue I'm facing is what should appear inside the modal only when the user clicks the button.

How come it won't work the way I'm doing it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Modal from 'react-modal';    
import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';
import Button from '../Buttons/Button';
import CheckoutButton from '../../../../components/UI/buttons/CheckoutButton/CheckoutButton';

import { CLOSE_MODAL, OPEN_MODAL } from "../../../../store/action/NoNameAction";

class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        isClicked: false
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    }

displayPerson = () => {
    this.setState({isClicked: true});

    if(this.state.isClicked) {
        return(
            <p>a random name</p>
        );
    }
}

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Button clicked={() => this.props.thisButtonChosen() && this.displayPerson()} label={"This button"}/>               

                <CheckoutButton clicked={() => this.props.openModalRedux()}/>

                <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
                 <p>{this.displayPerson}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.closeModalRedux()}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isOpen: state.global.isModalOpen
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        thisButtonChosen: () => dispatch({type: THIS_BUTTON_CHOSEN}),

        // Modal handlers
        openModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: OPEN_MODAL}),
        closeModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: CLOSE_MODAL})

    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Comment: `this.personChosen` is never set. `displayPerson` never called.

Comment: @marekful yeah that was a typo on my end.  I changed it to what you said, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.displayPerson` is returning a value depending on the next state update, but `setState` [is asynchronous](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710).
You can use the [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) in order to get the new `state`:

```
displayPerson = () => {
    this.setState({isClicked: true}, () => {
        if(this.state.isClicked) {
          return(
            <p>a random name</p>
          );
        }
    });
}
```

but even with this approach you could have some issues.
I recommend storing the random name in the state as well.

```
displayPerson = () => {
    const randomUserName = "some random user name...";
    this.setState({isClicked: true, randomName: randomUserName});
}
```

And just use it in `render`:

```
<p>{this.state.randomUserName}</p>
```

Of course you'll need to trigger `displayPerson`